# WordDocument.SaveAs results in an empty document

Tags: delphi, ms-word, word-2010

I'm using the unit `Word2010` to create a very simple word document.

I've written this code and everything looks fine; but in action, the saved document is always empty. Do you have any idea about why this is happening?

Here's my code:

```
procedure TConverter.Convert;
var
  A: TWordApplication;
  W: WordDocument;
begin
  A := TWordApplication.Create(Nil);
  try
    // Create document
    A.Visible := False;
    W := A.Documents.Add('', False, wdNewBlankDocument, True);

    // Write in document
    A.Selection.StartOf(wdStory, wdMove);
    A.Selection.InsertAfter('Hello World!');
    A.Selection.Collapse(wdCollapseEnd);
    A.Selection.EndOf(wdStory, wdMove);

    // Save document
    W.SaveAs(Target, wdFormatDocument, False, '', False, '', False, False, False, True, False, msoEncodingUTF8, True,
      False, wdCRLF, False);
    W.Close(wdDoNotSaveChanges, wdWordDocument, False);
    A.Quit;
  finally
    A.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: `wdDoNotSaveChanges` ?

Comment: Yes, at first I've used `SaveAs` to save it in a customized manner, then close it without saving changes because it's already saved.

Comment: Did you try just `W.SaveAs(Target);`? This does the trick for me, if you do not need to change the other parameters' default values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of your parameters to `SaveAs` is not correct. I've not bothered to check which one yet, but the best way to deal with this is to ask for default behaviour. Do that by passing `EmptyParam`:

```
W.SaveAs(Target, wdFormatDocument, EmptyParam, EmptyParam, EmptyParam, EmptyParam, 
  EmptyParam, EmptyParam, EmptyParam, EmptyParam, EmptyParam, EmptyParam, EmptyParam, 
  EmptyParam, EmptyParam, EmptyParam);
```

Pretty ugly isn't it?!

On the other hand, I would argue that this is more readable than the code in the question which forces you to count beyond 5, that is beyond the number of fingers on one hand. Which is always tricky!

OK, it looks like it is parameter number 10, `SaveFormsData`. You passed `True`. Changing that to be `False` will also result in your document's content appearing in the saved file. However, I stand by what I said above. You only really care about the first two parameters here, so use `EmptyParam` for all the others and thereby request default values for these parameters.

Comment: Thank you ;) So much ugly however!

Comment: This is quite an interesting issue. You could certainly use a class helper to hide away the ugly. If you used late bound COM then you could just omit the parameters. However, I'd argue that late bound COM has other disadvantages that outweigh that gain. On balance, I still prefer all the ugly `EmptyParam` to explicitly specified parameters. They are just as ugly and much harder to check and verify.